# background-image CSS property: how to do it right with Craft?

Tags: assets, css

My current code is:

```
#header { background-image: url('{{ sitePath }}/assets/toxicomental/header.png'); height: 150px; }
```

Still, I don't get the image showing.

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a function called `alias` that returns a defined [alias](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-aliases). A default alias is `@web` and it represents your base url,

```
background-image: {{ alias('@web') }}/path/to/image.jpg;
```

Would display the file `image.jpg` in `web/path/to/`

Comment: Thank you, but no luck:

background-image: url('alias('@web') }}/craft/templates/toxicomental/header.png'); Maybe did I not understand right?

Comment: Your image is at the totally wrong place. It should be in a subfolder of your `web` directory. Assets in your template folder are not public. You can as well remove the `url` function. Just do as I explained

Comment: Thank you, it's working now. Although, I am wondering, is it the only way to use the background-image property? Can't I use assets?

Comment: Found a satisfying solution: with header.png into the templates folder, renamed _header.png, #header { background-image: url(".header.png"); height: 150px; } works perfectly.

Comment: And it will drain much more resources since Craft handles the request so if you are going to create a popular site it will slow down

Answer (score 1):

You don't *need* the domain part at all. Why not use

```
background-image: /path/to/image.jpg;
```

Comment: Because it's much cleaner to use absolute paths in case he's going to move something

Comment: Is that not an absolute path? It includes the root. No matter the domain it will always point to the right place.

Comment: No yours is a relative path/url, it will point to the url relative from the current one

Comment: It points to the file from the web root. Though I guess it's Root Relative rather than absolute. So it's starting from the root, relative to the working directory right?